# Make Div like bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a div just like jumbotron class in Bootstrap. Tried everything on stack but got no where.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Center</title>
    <style>
    .centerlize {
    width: 100%;
    width: 100wh
    background-color: blue; 
    color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="centerlize">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can some of you help me understand what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `wh` it's `vh` for viewport height, and don't forget the semi-colon after the CSS property values. Unless you wanted `vw` for viewport width, but then your "jumbotron" would have no height.

```
.centerlize {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue; 
  color: white;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/y5k73sN2nE